Why does b'\x30' show up as 0?
If I try to output print(b'\x30') it shows as 0. Similarly b'\x31' is displayed as 1, etc. I need this byte string (class ) to be displayed, but with ONLY one backslash.
I tried
s = br"\x30"
print(s)

but the output I get is b'\\x30' (with two backslashes).
All conversions were done in UTF-8 encoding.

Do you care what the output is, or what the value is, or both? If you want the literal output b'\x30', print(r"b'\x30'") will do that, for example – but if you have an existing bytes that you want to display with all hex escapes, the solution is different. And if you only cared about the value – b"\x30" == b"0", nothing wrong there.

What is the actual problem you need to solve? Please ask about that directly.

That's just how it is. Converting to a string by str(s) and decoding it using s.decode('utf-8') doesn't help. Why do you want it to print otherwise anyway? How it is represented really doesn't change how it behave.

For example, my input is a regular string of numbers 002000010010 (possibly with spaces). Then at the output I want to get the byte string b'\x30\x30\x32\x30\x30\x30\x30\x31\x30\x30\x31\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20 \x30'. These are symbol codes using utf-8 encoding

This is important because only in this form can the machine read a byte string as input. The form of the output is important, but it must also be a class<bytes>.

What you are asking make no sense. It is like asking how come that x=5+5; print(x) doesn't print 5+5 but prints 10. It doesn't matter how you input x value, x=5+5, x=10, x=0xA, ... those are all the same. And prints as 10. Trying to influence how it is printed by tuning how you input the value makes no sense.

If you need to print it with a specific form of your own (one where single byte 48 is printed as b'\x30' and not is canonical form b'0') then you have to find a different way to print it, not a different way to input it. Default representation of b'\x30' aka b'0' is b'0'. Trying to change the value will make it even less likely to print as b'\x30'

If you need a printing function different than the default one, you'll have to write a print function (again, not to change the value of what is printed, but change the way you print it). Something of the sort print(''.join(f'\\x{b:02x}' for b in s))

With all comments, nobody could really go in a simple way: \x30 is the character of the digit zero, which it is different to having value 0. Because reasons, printable characters in ASCII starts from 32. Value zero is special on old serial communication (so possibly sent when no key are pressed) so it could in any case not be used efficiently on hardware without conversions.

@Максим Крайнов –
Regarding your bold example: Based on what rule are the spaces \x20, which aren't in the input, to be placed in the output?

Based on what you wrote in the comments, I think this code does what you want:
s = "00200001001         0"
print("".join(f"\\x{ord(c):02x}" for c in s)

Note that this only works as long as ord(c) < 256.
If you have characters outside of the ASCII table, I recommend this instead (even if all non-ASCII characters have ord(c) < 256):
s = "00200001001         0"
print("".join(f"\\x{b:02x}" for b in s.encode())

